# Print 5 times table from 1 o 12

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, math

I seem to have everything I need for the what I am trying to do. However, I can't seem to get it display how I want it to display.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>5 Times Table</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         /* Program to print the five times table from 1 to 12 in this format:
         5 x 1 = 5
         5 x 2 = 10
         5 x ...
         Input: There will be no user input, program will use a loop to create the 5 times table.
         Process: Define all the 5 times table between 1 and 12.
         Output: The 5 times table will be displayed.
         */
        function fiveTimesTable() {
            var result = 0;
            for (i=1; i<=12; i++){
                 result = "5 * " + i + result + i*5 + "<br>";
            var display =result;
            }
            document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
            }       
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Five Times Table From 1 - 12.</h1>
    <h2>Press the button to display the table.</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="fiveTimesTable()">Times Table</button>
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
           `
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to display the 5 times table in this format  
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x .....
I seem to have the loop but I can't figure out the rest.
Thanks for the welcome and prompt reply!

Answer (score 2):

Your code was close, but it'll be easier to understand if you break it up into its parts.

```
function fiveTimesTable() {
  var display = ""; // The table output HTML

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
     var multiplier = 5;
     var result = i*5;

     display += multiplier+" * "+i+" = "+result+"<br>"; //Add each line to our output HTML
  }

  document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
}
```

Check it out [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gpwpea).

Some challenges going forward, if you're interested.

1. Make your function able to display the table for any multiplier using parameters.
2. Put your table into an actual HTML table element.

Comment: You use the same multiplier for every iteration, so you might want to move that outside the loop.

Comment: @saadq That's a fair point but I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible for OP to understand. Variable scope gets confusing pretty quickly. :)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than what I was trying to do. I will keep in mind your advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tabla del 5</title>
    <script>`enter code here`
         /* Program to print the five times table from 1 to 12
         Input: The program will use a loop to create the 5 times table.
         Process: Write a defining  table and a program to display the five times tables
         Output: display the five times table from 1 to 12 in this format*/
        function FiveTimesTable() {
             var display = "";  
             for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                 var multiplier = 5;
                 var result = 5*i;
                 display += multiplier+" * "+i+" = "+result+"<br>"+"<br>";
             }  
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = display;
        }  
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Five Times Table</h2>
    <h3>Press the button to display the 5 times table</h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="FiveTimesTable()">Times Table</button>
    <div id="outputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer.